Convex combination of functions when weights are themselves functions
Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both convex functions. Let $p(x)$ be weakly increasing and have range $[0,1]$. Define $u(x)=p(x)f(x)+(1-p(x))g(x)$.
Are there any restictions I can place on $p(x)$ so $u(x)$ is always convex?
Short of $p(x)$ being constant of course since then $u(x)$ would be convex as the family of convex functions is closed under non-negative weighted sums.
Thanks in advance.

Try $p(x) = x^2, f(x) = x^2, g(x) = x^2+2$
